# Wordpress conditional function with category post

Tags: wordpress, conditional-statements

I have two category

Category 1 Category 2

As some post fall in both category.

Now I want to show the 15 post of Category 2 which is not is last five post of category 1. (15 post of Category 2 but if these post are in the last 5 post of category 1 just want to exclude them)

Is that possible to do? Any help or resources will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two seperate queries using WP_Query

First get first 5 posts in Category 1.  Loop through and get the post ids.

Then query for posts in Category two excluding the postIDs.

Something like:

```
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 5,
          'cat'            => '1',
);

$posts = new WP_Query( $args );

while ($posts->have_posts()) {
   $exclude_posts[] = $posts->the_ID();
}


$args = array('cat'=> '2',
          'post__not_in'   =>  $exclude_posts
);

$posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts using multiple loops

Comment: Thanks. As I have to call this query multiple times in index.php inside this loop. Can you please tell me how to do this inside this loop?

Can I define this filter in function.php and apply it here?

`<?php query_posts('showposts=5&cat=5'); if (have_posts()) : ?><?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a><?php endwhile; ?> <?php else : ?>  <?php endif; ?>`